# How to display the selections in an alert box when the button is clicked? (with Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I have done a drop down menu with some options and after i have put two radio buttons with the labels "a" and "b". At the end i have a button ...

I would like to ask, how i can connect all these?

I try to take a result like Germany win or lose according what you choose.

```html
<select>
    <option value="England">England</option>
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
</select>

<form action="demo_form.asp"> 
    <label for="win">win</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="win" value="win"><br>
    <label for="lose">lose</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="lose" value="lose"><br>
</form>
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var team = $('#team').val(),
        result = $('input[name=gender]:checked').val(),
        output = result 
          ? team + ' ' + result 
          : 'Select team and result!'; 
  
    alert(output);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="team">
  <option value="England">England</option>
  <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
</select>

<form action="demo_form.asp"> 
  <label for="win">win</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="win" value="win"><br>
  <label for="lose">lose</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="lose" value="lose"><br>
</form>
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML -

```
<select class="team">
<option value="England">England</option>
<option value="Germany">Germany</option>
</select>

<form action="demo_form.asp"> 
  <label for="win">win</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="win" value="win"><br>
  <label for="lose">lose</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="lose" value="lose"><br>
  </form>
  <button class="click">click</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

JS -

```
$(".click").click(function(){
    var team = $(".team").val()
    var outcome = $("#win").is(":checked") ? "wins" : "loses"
    alert(team + " " + outcome + "!")
})
```

Checks the value of the selected dropdown, checks to see which radio button is checked, and then pops open an alert window displaying the result

https://jsfiddle.net/t0uh81yL/1/

Comment: @William This answer has an error: `$("#win").checked` will always be equal to `undefined`... And for that reason `outcome` variable is wrong and also the alert message.

Comment: @YosvelQuintero thanks for catching that! I have fixed it

Answer (score 1):

First, give you Select an ID:

```
<select id="country">
```

Then, use this function, that gathers the values and shows an Alert:

```
function myFunction() {
  genderIs="unselected";
  if (document.getElementById('win').checked) {
  genderIs = document.getElementById("win").value;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('lose').checked) {
  genderIs = document.getElementById("lose").value;
  }

  countryIs = document.getElementById("country").value;
  alert ("Gender: " + genderIs + "\nCountry: " + countryIs);
}
```

One more thing...  Your Select should be inside your form.  There is no reason for it to be outside.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durbnpoisn/oraqL191/), just because...